# c++ exception: override what function does not return anything

Tags: c++, exception

In the following programm `std::cout << ex.what() << std::endl;` does not print anything.
What's the problem with this code?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstring>

class Interval_OutOfRange : public std::out_of_range {
public:
    std::stringstream ss;
    Interval_OutOfRange(int min, int max, int value)
        : std::out_of_range{"interval value out of range"}
    {
        ss << value << " is not inside intervall [" << min << ", " << max << "]";
    }

    char const * what() const noexcept override {
        return ss.str().c_str();
    }
}; 

template<int Min, int Max>
class Interval {
public:
    Interval(int value) : value_{value} {
        throw Interval_OutOfRange{Min, Max, value};
    }
    auto get() const { return value_; }
    auto set(int value) { value_ = value; }
private:
    int value_;
};

int main() {
    try {
        Interval<7, 17> obj(19);
    }
    catch (Interval_OutOfRange& ex) {
        std::cout << ex.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: `ss.str()` returns a temporary and then `ss.str().c_str()` returns a pointer to the internals of that temporary. But the temporary gets destroyed before the function exits so the function is returning a pointer to an object which has been destroyed. This results in undefined behaviour.

Comment: You should get rid of the `std::stringstream` altogether, and just pass the formatted string to the `out_of_range` constructor so the inherited `what()` will return it properly

Comment: why is the member a stringstream ?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ How much more minimal do you want it to be?  There is like 2 one like functions that aren't needed but the rest is.

Comment: Why does this code have a `std::stringstream ss;` as a member variable, since it no longer needs that stream after construction.  It just needs to retain the result of that stream into a `std::string s;` member variable, and use `return s.c_str();` in the `what` method.